# How can I avoid that my table starts in portrait mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, tablet

I have Windows 10 Home, Version 1803, Lenovo Miix 300. For some months it always starts in portrait mode and I have to manually switch it in Windows to landscape mode so that I can properly work with it. This phenomenon even appears with the keyboard connected when it should be clear for the machine that portrait mode does not make any sense.

I have reinstalled Windows, run Lenovo Vantage to update all drivers but it did not help.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The auto rotate function could be causing the problem.
You could try to completely disable auto rotate by opening the registry editor (regedit).
And then navigate to the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation
```

Change the values SensorPresent and the value Enable to 0.

Comment: I did that but it did not solve the problem.